# replace &lt; and &gt; when they are meeting certain conditions

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace `&lt;` with '<'

```
if &lt; has next symbol either # or pair /#
```

I want to replace `&gt;` with '>'

```
if &gt; is not between ()
```

I was trying to build regex myself (I am not experienced in them so the regex is malformed)

```
(?(&lt;[#|/#])<|)([^.]*?)(?!([^(&gt;*)))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have two difference replacement do it with separate regex commands like these:

```
"(&lt;)(#|(\/#))" => \1
```

and

```
"(\([^\)]*(&gt;)[^\(]*\))" => \3
```

And edit them to be supported by Java.

Comment: The first actually too. For example input message is `sdsdfsdfs sdfsdf sdf sd<br><br>&lt;#list tag&gt;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &lt;#if tag (tag &gt; comparsion) /&gt;<br>&lt;/#list&gt;<br><br>` and output is `sdsdfsdfs sdfsdf sdf sd<br><br>&lt;list tag&gt;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &lt;if tag (tag &gt; comparsion) /&gt;<br>&lt;list&gt;<br><br>`

Comment: Still returns `&lt;#list template&gt; &lt;#if template >&gt; &lt;/#if&gt;&lt;/#list&gt;`. It seems that `regex` is true only for `&gt;` inside `( )`